# Reference column based on multiple cell values in Google Query

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to return a value in a column based on two cell references.

My current query is:

```
=QUERY(A:T,"select A WHERE P = '"&S200&"' AND Q = '"&T200&"'")
```

Column A is a number, P is a string, and Q is a number.
S and T correspond to P and Q, respectively.

All it's returning is column headers.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Note the different quotes for the cell number reference.

```
=QUERY(A:T,"select A WHERE P = '"&S200&"' AND Q="&T200&"")
```