# QUERY syntax for using a 'cell range reference' after the 'where'

Tags: google-query-language

I'm trying to use a cell range reference instead of static values. I Know how to select only one cell as writen below :

=QUERY('sheet 1'!1:468;"Select I where G = '"&B2&"'";-1)

...  but not the whole range/column :

=QUERY('sheet 1'!1:468;"Select I where G = '"&**B2:B99**&"'";-1)

(with B2:B99 a query result from sheet 1)

...I keep getting a "Error" with the previous formula.

Thank you in advance,

Fred from France.

Answer (score 0):

I would love to know the answer to this as well. I'd like to be able to have my query search for where based on 3 different cell requisites. I want to be able to build that on top of this question that I asked here:

[My Question For A Google Query that selects from two values after a 'where' statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47188793/can-someone-help-me-write-a-google-query-that-selects-from-two-values-after-a-w)

EDIT ANSWER:

Try this, Note the different quotes for the cell number reference.

```
=QUERY(A:T,"select A WHERE P = '"&S200&"' AND Q="&T200&"")
```

Comment: Actually I think I found the answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46201053/reference-column-based-on-multiple-cell-values-in-google-query