# Select from two values after a 'where' statement

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

I'm trying to write a Select and Where query to search for an OR value after my Where statement.

```
=query('Jigsaw Stories'!A:O,"select * where K OR L = '" & B5 & "'",-1)
```

I get an error when putting in **where K OR L**.

*Extra note: The query works when I write it like this:
`=query('Jigsaw Stories'!A:O,"select * where K = '" & B5 & "'",-1)`*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=query('Jigsaw Stories'!A:O,"select * where K = '" & B5 & "'" OR L = '" & B5 & "'",-1)
```